# Create lm/glm class object using predetermined beta coefficients

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, lm, bayesian

I have a list of beta coefficients values that I generated through a Bayesian analysis in JAGs but would love to simply plug them into a simple function like lm() so that I can use the summary statistics which is available to the lm() or glm() class object in R. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Currently I have my linear model in an equation used for predictions that looks something like this:

```
simdata$B565USEmod<-scale(1.144+
  (da$longitude)*(-0.244)+
  (da$latitude)*(1.640)+
  (da$B_age_565)*(-0.488)+
  (da$B_decid_565)*(-0.276)+
  (da$B_volume_565)*(-9.219)+
  (da$B_height_565)*(-0.124)+
  (da$B_biomass_565)*(11.609))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: It would help to show, for the summaries you would like, how you would call them, and what you would expect the output to look like.